# aws-cli gateway how to encode newlines in integration response templates invoked from bash

Tags: bash, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I am using "aws apigateway update-integration-response" from a bash script to update an integration response template. my problem is that newlines did not appear in the web console.  I tried all combinations of slash n, back-slash n, even unicode for the newline without success.. below there is the bash command and the output as it appears in aws web console:

bash:

```
   echo "update integration response script mapping for ${CODE} ${2}"
   aws apigateway update-integration-response \
    --rest-api-id ${APIID} \
    --resource-id ${RESOURCEID} \
    --http-method ${METHOD} \
    --status-code ${CODE} \
    --patch-operations \
      "op='add',path='/responseTemplates/application~1json',value='#set(\$errorMessageObj = \$util.parseJson(\$input.path(\'\$.errorMessage\')))NEWLINE/nA//nB///nX////nC\nD\\nE\\\nF\\\\n  \u000A unicodeA Cg== unicodeB  #if(\"\$errorMessageObj.get(\'error-code\')\" != \"\")\n{\n    \"error-code\": \"\$errorMessageObj[\'error-code\']\",\n    \"error-message\": \"\$errorMessageObj[\'error-message\']\"\n}\\n#else\n{\n    \"error-code\": \"AWS\",\n    \"error-message\": \"\$input.path(\'\$.errorMessage\')\"\n}\n#end'"
```

Output in the aws web console:

```
#set($errorMessageObj = $util.parseJson($input.path('$.errorMessage')))NEWLINE/nA//nB///nX////nC\nD\nE\nF\n  \u000A unicodeA Cg== unicodeB  #if("$errorMessageObj.get('error-code')" != "")\n{\n    "error-code": "$errorMessageObj['error-code']",\n    "error-message": "$errorMessageObj['error-message']"\n}\n#else\n{\n    "error-code": "AWS",\n    "error-message": "$input.path('$.errorMessage')"\n}\n#end
```